# auto refesh image automatically by using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to update an image cyclically by javascript (jQuery) to not load the whole content of a page.
Because it is a webcam image, which always has the same name, there is the problem, that the cache doesn't always show the current image.
Therefore I added a timestamp to the image name via Javascript, so that this is always a new image name and the browser updates it.
I want to change two things:

a) Currently the image is in an external file cam.php
Is it possible to change without PHP and include so that only the DIV is reloaded on the page and there are no more two pages?

b) At the moment the first image (from the first call of the page) and the most current one is always displayed, the first one disappears after 2sec. ca and then only the current one is displayed. This is surely also a cache problem. Am I right and how can this be changed?

```
  <head>

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Refresh File cam.php every 5 sec.
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#refresh").load("cam.php");
        var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
            $("#refresh").load('cam.php?' + 1*new Date());
        }, 5000);
    });
    </script>       

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="card-deck mb-12 text-center">
        <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">       
          <div class="card-body" id="refresh">
            <?php
            // include cam.php
            require_once('cam.php');
            ?>  
          </div>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>  

  </body>
</html>
```

and the cam.php file

```
<script>
// create timestamp and attach to picture name
$("#myimg").attr("src", $("#myimg").attr("src")+"?timestamp=" + new Date().getTime());
</script>

<img src="https://www.domain.de/images/mega.jpg" id="myimg" class="img-fluid" >
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

When the image loads, schedules it to be reloaded in 1 second.

Try this -

```
<img src='someurl.com/someimage.ext' onload='imageRefresh(this, 1000);'>
```

Javascript:

```
<script language='javascript'>
 function imageRefresh(img, timeout) {
    setTimeout(function() {
     var d = new Date;
     var http = img.src;
     if (http.indexOf("&d=") != -1) { http = http.split("&d=")[0]; } 

     img.src = http + '&d=' + d.getTime();
    }, timeout);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, but this doesn't work. The image is no longer updated.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but the image will be loaded only once and will not be displayed at the next "refresh".

Answer (score 0):

I have now implemented this solution because it works quite well.  Thanks for the help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Picture Refresh
setInterval('reloadImages()', 5000); // every 5 seconds autorefresh
});
function reloadImages()
{
$('#campic').attr('src', 'https://www.test.com/picture.jpg?' + Math.random()); 
}
</script>
```